# How to filter column names from multiindex dataframe for a specific condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "empid" : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    "empname" : ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f'],
    "empcity" : ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff']
})
df1

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "empid" : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    "empname" : ['a', 'b','m','d','n','f'],
    "empcity" : ['aa','bb','cc','ddd','ee','fff']
})
df2

df_all = pd.concat([df1.set_index('empid'),df2.set_index('empid')],axis='columns',keys=['first','second'])
df_all

df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis = 'columns')[df1.columns[1:]]
df_final

orig = df1.columns[1:].tolist()
print (orig)
['empname', 'empcity']

df_final = (df_all.stack()
                  .assign(comparions=lambda x: x['first'].eq(x['second']))
                  .unstack()
                  .swaplevel(axis = 'columns')
                  .reindex(orig, axis=1, level=0))
print (df_final)
```

How to filter level[0] column name list where comparions = False from the dataframe df_final(consider there are more than 300 column like this at level 0)

[image]

Comment: Super, wow looks expected ouput? It is DataFrame? List? How looks from this data.

Comment: preferably list

Comment: So here how looks this list?

Comment: empname, empcity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First test if in level `comparions` are all `True`s by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
s = df_final.xs('comparions', level=1, axis=1).all()
```

And then invert mask for test at least one `False` with filter indices:

```
L = s.index[~s].tolist()
print (L)
['empname', 'empcity']
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael this is to the point

Comment: absolutely it was helpful.. accepted it.. thank you :)